# Enabling HTTPS with GeoServer with SQL extension

Tags: geoserver, encryption

I have set up GeoServer (2.15.11) on a Windows server machine and have connected it to an Azure database using the SQL Server extension.  However, because SQL queries and parameters are done in plain text, I wanted to encrypt them.  Would I have to modify the SQL Server extension in GeoServer to do this, or can I implement HTTPS to do this through TLS certificates?  In the case of the latter, would I have to set that up on the server that GeoServer is on, or would that have to be done on the Azure server where the database is (which unfortunately I don't have direct access to)?

Comment: It would be done at the Azure end - simply use HTTPS in the connection url on the GeoServer end

Comment: Are you trying to use HTTPS connecting to GeoServer, or trying to get encryption (SSL) between GeoServer and SQL Server?

Comment: the latter; i'm trying to use TLS so communications between geoserver and sql server are encrypted.  Essentially, instead of my current url of http://localhost:8080, I want to use https://localhost:8443 for all my geoserver requests.